# jQuery Ajax is not running on the same page but redirecting to the page instead?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to combined a Bootstrap Validator action with an Ajax call. The verification part works correctly, but for some reason it redirects to the actual page of the call instead of running it on the same page. What part of my code is wrong here?

```
$('.newsletter').bootstrapValidator({
                  message: 'This value is not valid',
                  live: 'submitted',
                  submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {

                                  e.preventDefault();
                                  var postdata = $('.newsletter-subscribe form').serialize();
                                  $.ajax({
                                      type: 'POST',
                                      url: 'newsletter.php',
                                      data: postdata,
                                      dataType: 'json',
                                      success: function(json) {
                                          if(json.valid == 1) {
                                             $('.newsletter-tab').hide();
                                              $('.success-message').css('display','block');
                                          }
                                          else if(json.valid == 0) {
                                             $('.newsletter-tab').hide();
                                              $('.exists-message').css('display','block');
                                          }
                                          else {
                                             $('.newsletter-tab').hide();
                                             $('.error-message').css('display','block');
                                          }
                                      },
                                      timeout: 10000
                                  });

                  },
                  feedbackIcons: {
                      valid: '',
                      invalid: '',
                      validating: ''
                  },
                  fields: {
                      newsletter_email: {
                          validators: {
                              notEmpty: {
                                  message: 'Email is required'
                              },
                              emailAddress: {
                                  message: 'Email must be valid'
                              }
                          }
                      }


                  }
              });
```

Comment: Did you try to make breakpoints (alert or colsole.log) inside success block? At what point does redirection happen?

Comment: Can you post your complete files or zip it on wetransfer ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390010/jquery-validation-plugin-submithandler-not-preventing-default-on-submit-when-ma . Possible duplicate

Comment: Also have a look at my question, which I asked some time ago and got some valid answers. It has much in common with yours - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183737/unable-to-submit-a-form-on-the-first-click-event

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `return false;` at the end of your code would change the behaviour of your submit button.

Comment: `return false` is like panacea in JavaScript. I think there should be some configs (like standardSubmit:false in ExtJS) or at least appropriate function calls like e.preventDefault(). =)

Comment: true that. He has the e.preventDefault() :/

Comment: I just tried that ...didn't work. Neither with or without e.preventDefault.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @bwest I wish I could but I could not since I did not have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution should look like this:

```
$('.newsletter').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    live: 'submitted',
    submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
         var postdata = $('.newsletter-subscribe form').serialize();
         $.ajax({
             ....
         });
    }
});

$('.newsletter').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```